# Laravel REST API not sending Authorization header with https

Tags: laravel, rest, authentication

The API is working fine on localhost with `http`. Unfortunately it is not sending Authorization header with `https`.
Any sort of help is appreciated.

Output of `the apache_request_headers()`

```
    Array
(
    [Host] => beakns.com
    [Connection] => keep-alive
    [Cache-Control] => no-cache
    [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
    [Postman-Token] => 29cd28d2-fb75-c588-dcee-f6f42bc280d8
    [Accept] => */*
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate, sdch, br
    [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.8
    [Cookie] => XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InBCT1ppdWpaUzFNUmthQTBsZ1JHeVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWWdqdklVblJOTkFxNVJpaklsXC9XWWZQMjc1WUVDK0ZNWk16aXA1UjBvanJBXC9oamhDa2NxRWxNOElhR0p4R09KeUtiNmdkalQ4N2ZHcE9NdEpMNlMrZz09IiwibWFjIjoiZjQ2NTEyY2RmN2RhNzI2ZDQ1MDNiZmZkNjkxNDI3ODNiMWMxZDQ1NjU4ODFiYjFkYTQxN2QzNGJkMjk4NmI5MCJ9; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImQ3RHV5c3A4SGJtU2NVSTY3dm9vS3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiMkJ0ZkJzXC9wcWUzZTFmN3c2Sm5Hb2RGZzVaSTBYTGdmc2hGanU2SVZGbHU1bExjMTJcL0taaVwvZjRPT0o1cDZNQ3YrN1owSFBVeTlNaUFWeVo4ZnYwNGc9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImE4NmJkZTM5ZDEyOGIyYmVkNWFlOGU0ZmJlYTUwZjgwODU4ZDhiMTA2MWQwYWNiZGI5MDQ2NjhmZGVjMzdlYWQifQ%3D%3D
    [X-Https] => 1
)
```

Comment: Check `apache_request_headers()` It should be in there. Apache blocks it from the `$_SERVER` superglobal. Let me know. Cheers!

Comment: @WesleyPeeters, its not present there: Updated